# ASP.Net debug directory monitoring HttpException

Tags: asp.net, debugging, httpexception

When I start my ASP.Net 4.0 web app in debug mode, I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.Web.HttpException occurred
  Message=Invalid file name for file monitoring: 'C:\src\main-232\src\ZNode\Znode_MultiFront\Web\Controls\Cat5\Navigation'. Common reasons for failure include:
- The filename is not a valid Win32 file name.
- The filename is not an absolute path.
- The filename contains wildcard characters.
- The file specified is a directory.
- Access denied.
  Source=System.Web
  ErrorCode=-2147024809
  WebEventCode=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.AddFileMonitor(String file)
  InnerException:
```

The thing is, the file this is pointing to IS a directory, so why does Visual Studio 2010 think it's a file? I'm running this on IIS 7 on my local machine

Comment: I'm just running the ASP.NET Dev Server and getting this error. My folder is [WebApp]\Controls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The good news: it doesn't seem to have any knock-on effects
The bad news: I haven't figured out the cause or a solution
The workaround: Disable break-on-exception for `HttpException` (Debug->Exception), and filter these out in your logs. You can still capture other HttpException in debug mode by placing a breakpoint in `Application_Error` (if you have implmented it - but you should have anyway)

Comment: How does one do this in VS2013?

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem and by checking the `Enable Just My Code` checkbox option in the Options: `Tools->Options->Debugging->General`, I got it working.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar exception when I am troubleshooting `HttpException` arising in `Application_Error` itself while redirecting to Error/Index action. I had to uncheck `HttpException` in Debug > Exceptions dialog to remove this error. Then it redirected to Error/Index as expected without any side-effects from this mysterious exception. At that time Visual studio is in debugging mode.